# Hide all table rows after a specific number?

Tags: jquery, hide

I'd like to write some code where it displays a complete listing for a year, but initially only show the first 6 weeks (so, 42 days) and then you can click a button to view the rest (no need for a toggle).

I was going to do this using PHP, and setting a class on each of the ones I'd want to hide, which is fine, I guess, I just wasn't sure if there was a more efficient way of doing it in jQuery.

Answer (score 15):

```
$("table tr:gt(5)").hide();
```

will hide all of them after/*[greater than](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)* the sixth row.

Comment: just tried this and it's incredibly simple, and works perfectly, thank you! the slice method looks great too, depending on what I need it for.

Answer (score 3):

slice() - http://api.jquery.com/slice/